# Custom InputDate in Blazor in my dynamic form

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a dynamic form which (for sake of demonstrating my issue) presents all the data fed to it from the datatable in a table format.

I have a date field and cannot use html5 input of type date since it does not work in Safari.

I am not sure if this is the right approach I create a custom Date component with the InputDate assuming I could bind the row[columnname] to the parameter variable of the component and bind it .

But I am not able to bind the value to the component from the parent since it is not a variable, property or indexer.

How can I use the InputDate to accept a value from Datarow like ex: (datarow[ColumnName].tostring())
Check the code snippet for what kind of value (i.e.Datarow)I am trying to bind to the InputDate.

Parent example:

```
 @for(int i=0;i< Table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            
            <tr>
                @if(!column.IsDateType)
                {
                    <td>@ListData.DataView.Table.Rows[i][col.Name]</td>
                }
    else{
   <Date  @bind-DateValue="Convert.ToDateTime(drow[col.Name].ToString())" />

//below not added since does not work
//@onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs _e) => { drow[col.Name] = Convert.ToDateTime(_e.Value.ToString()); })"
}

            </tr>
        }
```

Date component:

```
<h3>Date</h3>
<InputDate @bind-Value="DateValue"/>
@code {

    private DateTime dateVal;

    [Parameter]
    public DateTime DateValue {
        get => dateVal;
        set
        {
            if(dateVal != value)
            {
                dateVal = value;
                if (DateValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    DateValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<DateTime> DateValueChanged { get; set; }

}
```